# My scraper can only get the first page of html when scrapping an e-commercial platform using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scrapping `tmall.com` using **selenium**. Every time my program switch to another page and try to get the source html of the page, it always returns that of the first page. The page displayed in the browser is the correct target page, but the html text I get is always the first page's. My browser is Chrome.

This is part of my getting html text function:

```
def get_page_info():
    html = driver.page_source
    doc = PyQuery(html)
    g_page_config_text = doc('script:contains("g_page_config")').text()
    ...
```

This is part of my main function:

```
for i in range(2, 101):
    index_page(i)
    slider_verification()
    get_page_info()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(4.0, 7.0))
```

How can I fix that?

I tried `sleep()` enough time to wait for the webpage completely loaded, but it didn't work. I don't know whether it's the anti-scraping method working.

Answer (score 0):

That page will block you if it detects unusual traffic (eg. a Selenium bot):

[image]

The three main ways of avoiding Selenium-detection by websites are:

1: [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

2: [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in undetected mode. (Use `--undetected` or `--uc` as a `pytest` command-line option.)

3: [selenium-stealth](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth)

Here's an example of a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script that bypasses Cloudflare:

(First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run with `python`)

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but  I've already taken the slider verification into consideration. The verification problem may cause none returned data instead of data from the same page. I think my problem is the information-extracting method, since the hash value of the html changes every new page while the extracted information 'g_page_config_text' doesn't. Still much obliged!